# How to center the table?

Tags: tables

I have a table which looks shifted to the right:

[image]
I have been trying

```
\begin{center}
\centering
\scalebox{0.9}{
```

But it does not help. How can I move to the center?
The code is below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
%\sisetup{table-format=2.1}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\begin{center}
\scalebox{0.9}{
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l SSSSSS @{}} % @{} serves to suppress white space at ends of table

\toprule
%V=10   &  \multicolumn{5}{c @{}}{     }\\ 
%\cmidrule(l){2-6}
  $\min(V), K$  & { $\min(V), K$  } & {  $\min(V), K$  } & {  $\min(V), K$  } & {  $\min(V), K$  } & {  $\min(V), K$  } & {  $\min(V), K$  }  \\
 real $\mu,\sigma$  & {(0.01,0.03)} & {(-0.005,0.03)} & {(0.005,0.03)} & {(0.005,0.15)} & {(-0.005,0.15)}  & {  (0.05,0.15)  } \\
\midrule
Proxy method        & 59.0 & 18.0 & 17.3 &  5.8 & 5.8 &2 \\
Ronn-Verma      &  0.9 & 66.6 & 16.7 & 10.7 & 5.1 & 5.8 \\
Transformed MLE         &  1.4 & 16.6 & 70.8 &  8.0 & 3.1 &5.8 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\caption{ CAPTION}
\label{tab:111}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{center}...\centering`? ;-) Don't use `\begin{center}...\end{center}` in a floating environment like `table`. Most likely your table is just too wide in order to be centered and leaks into margins

Comment: as suggested by @ChristianHupfer, the table is indeed too wide for the page, and extends into the right margin.

Comment: Dear @Zarko, Mico, Bernard and everybody else. Thank you for such a quick answers! I am sorry, I can not accept all answers. I will be using Zarko's option, as his last table is even better than I could imagine!

Comment: Dear all, Could you please also tell where to find information on what S mean in \begin{tabular}{ l SSSSSS }; I could not find also how to work with tables, do you know any convenient editor for tables? I am using TexShop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
%\sisetup{table-format=2.1}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{ l SSSSSS } % @{} serves to suppress white space at ends of table
\toprule
%V=10   &  \multicolumn{5}{c @{}}{     }\\
%\cmidrule(l){2-6}
  $\min(V), K$  & { $\min(V), K$  } & {  $\min(V), K$  } & {  $\min(V), K$  } & {  $\min(V), K$  } & {  $\min(V), K$  } & {  $\min(V), K$  }  \\
 real $\mu,\sigma$  & {(0.01,0.03)} & {(-0.005,0.03)} & {(0.005,0.03)} & {(0.005,0.15)} & {(-0.005,0.15)}  & {  (0.05,0.15)  } \\
\midrule
Proxy method        & 59.0 & 18.0 & 17.3 &  5.8 & 5.8 & 2      \\
Ronn-Verma          & 0.9  & 66.6 & 16.7 & 10.7 & 5.1 & 5.8    \\
Transformed MLE     & 1.4  & 16.6 & 70.8 &  8.0 & 3.1 &5.8     \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{ CAPTION}
\label{tab:111}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

but result is table which require magnify lens for reading :(

[image]

maybe you will liked the following redesign of your table.

**edit:**
in case that you like enclose some numbers in parenthesis then `\sisetup` had be accordingly changed:

```
\sisetup{input-symbols = {()},
         table-space-text-post=\ ,% <-- for spacing of )
         detect-weight,
         table-format=3.1}% added one digit for space for (
```

as example i modify *mwe* below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%-------------------------------------- only for show page layout
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.25pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\sisetup{input-symbols = {()},
     table-space-text-post=\ ,% <-- for spacing of )
     detect-weight,
     table-format=3.1}% added one digit for space for (
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{ l SSSSSS } % @{} serves to suppress white space at ends of table
    \toprule
    &  \multicolumn{5}{c}{$\min(V), K$}     \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-7}
 real $\mu,\sigma\ \times 10^{-3}$  
    & {$(10,30)$} & {$(-5,30)$} & {$(5,30)$} & {$(5,150)$} & {$(-5,150)$} & {$(50,150)$} \\
\midrule
Proxy method        
    & 59.0        & 18.0        & 17.3       &  5.8        & 5.8          & 2           \\
    & (59.0)      & (18.0)      & (17.3)     &  5.8        & 5.8          & (11.1)      \\
Ronn-Verma      
    &  0.9        & 66.6        & 16.7       & 10.7        & 5.1          & 5.8         \\
Transformed MLE         
    &  1.4        & 16.6        & 70.8       &  8.0        & 3.1          & 5.8         \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{ CAPTION}
\label{tab:111}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear @Zarko, could you please tell how to put numbers in parenthesis? I want to some estimate and its standard error( typically it is written in parenthesis)

Comment: @StochasticIntegrationStudent,see edit of my answer.

Comment: Dear @Zarko, what if I want to put numbers like 1.3\times 10^{-4} in the cell? Is there a way to do it in similar way to:\sisetup{input-symbols = {()}

Comment: now i notice that you open new question about parenthesis. i will try provide an answer there.

Answer (score 5):

Table design really matters when it comes to space utilization and readability. I removed much noise from the table as I understand it (too many repetition of `$\min(V)$, K`, parentheses, etc.) and redesigned the rows and columns from scratch. I don't know if it appeals to you, or even conveys the information as you intended, but in my opinion the table now is clear and readable. No text resizing, no scaling, or whatever, just the contents of the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}*{2}{S[table-format=3.4]} *{3}{S[table-format=8.6]@{}} }
\toprule
             &                 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$\min(V)$, K}                  \\ \cmidrule{3-5}
{real $\mu$} & {real $\sigma$} & {Proxy method} & {Ronn-Verma} & {Transformed MLE} \\ \midrule
 0.01        & 0.03            &  59.0          &   0.9        &   1.4             \\
-0.005       & 0.03            &  18.0          &  66.6        &  16.6             \\ 
 0.005       & 0.03            &  17.3          &  16.7        &  70.8             \\ 
 0.005       & 0.15            &   5.8          &  10.7        &   8.0             \\
-0.005       & 0.15            &   5.8          &   5.1        &   3.1             \\   
 0.05        & 0.15            &   2.0          &   5.8        &   5.8             \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{CAPTION}
\label{tab:111}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method that uses a `tabular*` environment, along with a `\scriptsize` directive, to assure that the table fits inside the width of the text block.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{4}{S[table-format=2.1]} *{2}{S[table-format=1.1]}}

\toprule
  $\min(V), K$  & { $\min(V), K$  } & {  $\min(V), K$  } & {  $\min(V), K$  } & {  $\min(V), K$  } & {  $\min(V), K$  } & {  $\min(V), K$  }  \\
 real $\mu$, $\sigma$  & {(0.01,0.03)} & {($-0.005$,0.03)} & {(0.005,0.03)} & {(0.005,0.15)} & {($-0.005$,0.15)}  & {  (0.05,0.15)  } \\
\midrule
Proxy method   & 59.0 & 18.0 & 17.3 &  5.8 & 5.8 &2   \\
Ronn-Verma     &  0.9 & 66.6 & 16.7 & 10.7 & 5.1 & 5.8\\
Transformed MLE&  1.4 & 16.6 & 70.8 &  8.0 & 3.1 &5.8 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\caption{CAPTION}
\label{tab:111}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use marginal notes, you'll have more decent default outer margins with the `geometry` package, and it is  enough to set the table font to `\small` to make the table fit margins:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} %
\sisetup{table-format=2.1}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
  \centering\small
  \begin{tabular}{@{} l*{6}{S} @{}} % @{} serves to suppress white space at ends of table
    \toprule
    $\min(V), K$ & { $\min(V), K$ } & { $\min(V), K$ } & { $\min(V), K$ } & { $\min(V), K$ } & { $\min(V), K$ } & { $\min(V), K$ } \\
    real $\mu,\sigma$ & {$ (0.01,0.03) $} & {$ (-0.005,0.03) $} & {$ (0.005,0.03) $} & {$ (0.005,0.15) $} & {$ (-0.005,0.15) $} & { $ (0.05,0.15) $ } \\
    \midrule
    Proxy method & 59.0 & 18.0 & 17.3 & 5.8 & 5.8 & 2 \\
    Ronn-Verma & 0.9 & 66.6 & 16.7 & 10.7 & 5.1 & 5.8 \\
    \rlap{Transformed MLE} & 1.4 & 16.6 & 70.8 & 8.0 & 3.1 & 5.8 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{ CAPTION}
  \label{tab:111}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: By loading `geometry` you are changing the text width.

Comment: I know. That's why I added ‘if you don't use marginal notes’ – in which case the outer margin is unnecessarily wide.