# Wish to use parentheses as ordinary symbols in an "S" column

Tags: tables, siunitx, parentheses

Could you please tell me how to use parentheses -- `(` and `)` -- as ordinary symbols in a table that uses the `S` column type of the `siunitx` package?

I want to have in the "cells" some point estimates, followed by either their standard errors or the associated t-statistics, which are typically written inside parentheses.

I do it, but I get an for an number 1.90 in the parenthesis

```
 \begin{table}
\sisetup{table-format=2.1}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{ l SSSSSS } 
    \toprule
    &  \multicolumn{5}{c}{$\min(V), K$}     \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-7}
 real $\mu,\sigma\ \times 10^{-3}$  
    & {$(10,30)$} & {$(-5,30)$} & {$(5,30)$} & {$(5,150)$} & {$(-5,150)$} & {$(50,150)$} \\
\midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{mu} & 0.01  & -0.005 & 0.005 & 0.01  & -0.005 & 0.05 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{sigma} & 0.03  & 0.03  & 0.03  & 0.15  & 0.15  & 0.15 \\
\midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{proxy} & 0.02960 & 0.02957 & 0.0299 & 0.1494 & 0.1491 & 0.1489 \\
        $\times 10^{-4}$  & (1.90)  & 1.73 & 2.39 & 8.66 & 9.99 & 9.14 \\

          \multicolumn{1}{l}{system} & 0.0302 & 0.0299 & 0.0303 & 0.1582 & 0.2591 & 0.1693 \\
      $\times 10^{-4}$    & 3.54 & 2.47 & 2.80 & 37.4 & 209 & 518 \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{duan} & 0.02975 & 0.02970 & 0.0300 & 0.1486 & 0.1492 & 0.1462 \\
       $\times 10^{-4}$   & 1.89 & 1.73 & 2.42 & 9.44 & 10 & 9.2 \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{ CAPTION}
\label{tab:111}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Just add the instruction `\sisetup{input-symbols = {()}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instruct the `siunitx` package to treat `(` and `)` as "ordinary" input symbols. This may be accomplished by providing the instruction

```
\sisetup{input-symbols = {()}}
```

Here's the modified table, with a few more formatting tweaks applied:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,graphicx,booktabs}
\sisetup{input-symbols = {()} , group-digits = false}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\sisetup{table-format=2.5} % default format for 'S' columns
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
     l SS *{4}{S[table-format=-1.4]}}
\toprule
    &  \multicolumn{6}{c}{$\min(V), K$}   \\
\cmidrule{2-7}
    real $\mu$, $\sigma$ $\times 10^{-3}$  
    & {$(10,30)$} & {$(-5,30)$} & {$(5,30)$} & {$(5,150)$} & {$(-5,150)$} & {$(50,150)$} \\
\midrule
    mu & 0.01  & -0.005 & 0.005 & 0.01  & -0.005 & 0.05 \\
    sigma & 0.03  & 0.03  & 0.03  & 0.15  & 0.15  & 0.15 \\
\midrule
    proxy $\times 10^{-4}$ & 0.02960 & 0.02957 & 0.0299 & 0.1494 & 0.1491 & 0.1489 \\
        & (1.90)  & 1.73 & 2.39 & 8.66 & 9.99 & 9.14 \\

    system $\times 10^{-4}$& 0.0302 & 0.0299 & 0.0303 & 0.1582 & 0.2591 & 0.1693 \\
          & (3.54) & 2.47 & 2.80 & {37.4} & {209} & {518} \\
    \\
    duan $\times 10^{-4}$& 0.02975 & 0.02970 & 0.0300 & 0.1486 & 0.1492 & 0.1462 \\
         & (1.89) & 1.73 & 2.42 & 9.44 & 10 & 9.2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\caption{CAPTION}
\label{tab:111}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear @Mico, thanks a lot!  Could you please tell how to use  $1.4 \times 10^{-4}$ or $1.4E-04$ in cells?

Comment: What does "S" column mean?

Comment: @StochasticIntegrationStudent - Which cells are we talking about?

Comment: @StochasticIntegrationStudent - `S` is a column type provided the `siunitx` package.

Comment: Ok, I see. I could not understand the following: what if I want to put not a number in a parenthesis, say (0.015) or just a number  0.015 but the "scientific notation", i.e 1.5\times10^{-3}?

Comment: @StochasticIntegrationStudent - Just use another macro of the `siunitx` package: `\num`. E.g., `\num{1.4e-4}`. If space is at a premium, write `\num[tight-spacing]{1.4e-4}`, which will reduce the amount of whitespace around the `\times` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

considering your comment below of my answer on question [how-to-center-the-table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388250/how-to-center-the-table/388251), the *mwe* is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%-------------------------------------- only for show page layout
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.25pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\sisetup{
input-symbols = {()},
table-number-alignment = center,
table-format=3.2,
table-figures-exponent = 1,
table-align-exponent=false
}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}l *{6}{S}
                @{}}
    \toprule
    &  \multicolumn{5}{c}{$\min(V), K$}     \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-7}
 real $\mu,\sigma\ \times 10^{-3}$
    & {$(10,30)$} & {$(-5,30)$} & {$(5,30)$} & {$(5,150)$} & {$(-5,150)$} & {$(50,150)$} \\
\midrule
$\mu$               & 1.3e-3    & -0.005    & 0.005     & 0.01      & -0.005    & 0.05      \\
$\sigma$            & 0.03      & 0.03      & 0.03      & 0.15      & 0.15      & 0.15      \\
\midrule
proxy               & 0.02960   & 0.02957   & 0.0299    & 0.1494    & 0.1491    & 0.1489    \\
$\times 10^{-4}$    & (1.90)    & 1.73      & 2.39      & 8.66      & 9.99      & 9.14      \\
system              & 0.0302    & 0.0299    & 0.0303    & 0.1582    & 0.2591    & 0.1693    \\
$\times 10^{-4}$    & (3.54)    & 2.47      & 2.80      & 37.4      & 209       & 518       \\
                    &           &           &           &           &           &           \\
duan                & 0.02975   & 0.02970   & 0.0300    & 0.1486    & 0.1492    & 0.1462    \\
$\times 10^{-4}$    & (1.89)    & 1.73      & 2.42      & 9.44      & 10        & 9.2       \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{CAPTION}
\label{tab:s-table}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of `1.3e-3`, I'd write `\num{1.3e-3}` or even `\num[tight-spacing]{1.3e-3}`. I'd also turn of digit grouping, at least among the numbers with 5 decimals.

Comment: @Mico, but then align is different. however with your suggestion is then possible to define table-format for each column separately what i didn't succeed to do with my solution.